# MongoDB Replica Set: Can't Add Member/Connect

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm building a MongoDB replicaset w/ three Ubuntu 14 servers.

I'm connected to the primary server and authenticated w/ `userAdminAnyDatabase` and `clusterAdmin` privileges.

When I run `rs.add(xx.xx.xx.xx:27017)`, I get this error:

`exception: set name does not match the set name host xx.xx.xx.xx:27017 expects`

I've tried using the IP address, external hostname, and internal hostname.

I have `xx.xx.xx.xx rs2` in my `/etc/hosts` file and use `rs2` in the config file of the server I want to add (`replSet=rs2`). No matter what I try, it says the name doesn't match.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed it! The issue was a result of having different values for `replSet` in `/etc/mongod.conf`.

I thought the servers should be named uniquely -- this is incorrect.

Each server in the replicaset must have the same value for `replSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a result of having different values for replSet in /etc/mongod.conf. I thought the servers should be named uniquely -- this is incorrect. Each server in the replicaset must have the same value for replSet.